# Find duplicates in the same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns - artist, release_id

What query can I run to show duplicate records?

e.g. my table is

```
ArtistX : 45677
ArtistY : 378798
ArtistX : 45677
ArtistZ : 123456
ArtistY : 888888
ArtistX : 2312
ArtistY: 378798
```

The query should show

```
ArtistX : 45677
ArtistX : 45677
ArtistY : 378798
ArtistY : 378798
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use a grouping across the columns of interest to work out if there are duplicates.

```
SELECT
    artist, release_id, count(*) no_of_records
FROM table
GROUP BY artist, release_id
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT
    artist, release_id, count(*) no_of_records, group_concat(id)
FROM table
GROUP BY artist, release_id
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

also adding group_concat(id) gets you all ids of the duplicates.

Comment: Yours is the only one that answers the question thanks to the group_concat

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT id,artist,COUNT(*) FROM myTable
GROUP BY artist, release_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from table where artist IN (select artist from table group by artist having count(ID)>1) and release_id IN (select release_id from table group by release_id having count(release_id)>1);
```

Will Fetch:

```
ArtistX : 45677
ArtistX : 45677
ArtistY : 378798
ArtistY : 378798
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try something like this

```
select artist, count(*) from mytable group by artist having count(*) > 1;
```

wich would output

```
artist   count(*)
45677    2
378798   2
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use this query for the same result. it works for me

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, list.address FROM list
INNER JOIN (SELECT address FROM list
GROUP BY address HAVING count(id) > 1) dup ON list.address = dup.address
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT row, COUNT(row) AS num FROM mytable GROUP BY row HAVING (num > 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT artist, count(*) 
FROM tableName 
GROUP BY artist 
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,artist,COUNT(id) as found FROM table GROUP by id HAVING found > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.ARTIST,A.RELEASE_ID FROM ARTISTS A
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT 'X' FROM ARTISTS B
WHERE B.ARTIST = A.ARTIST AND B.RELEASE_ID = A.RELEASE_ID
GROUP BY B.ARTIST,B.RELEASE_ID
HAVING COUNT(B.ARTIST)>1)
ORDER BY A.ARTIST;
```

Answer (score 0):

This method might not be great for you, but if you ever want to get rid of duplicates and do this while making sure they are duplicates indeed you can try this:

1. duplicate your `table1` into `table2`, for example like this:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT * FROM table1;
   ```
2. add a new column to `table1`, for example, name it to count
3. run a query (this assumes `release_id` should an unique column):

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1 SET t1.kount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 AS t2 WHERE t1.release_id = t2.release_id)
```

4. drop table `table2`
5. use `table1`.kount to find your duplicates and remove them or something. Preferably in `PHP/Python/Perl`. This way you can, for example, make sure they are indeed duplicates and just have the same release_id. The same `release_id` might be given by accident and titles, years of publication, etc. might be different. So just put your code here to filter the duplicates (pseudocode):

```
foreach (sql(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE kount>1)) do
    //do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

```
SELECT W.artist, W.release_id FROM table W, table W1 
WHERE W.artist= W1.artist AND W.release_id = W1.release_id;
```

Answer (score -2):

**If you have more unique column in one row, you can use this:**

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id in(
    SELECT x.id 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT *,count(id) cc FROM table group by col1,col2,col3... 
    ) x
    WHERE x.cc>1
)
```